# Select a single forecast plot using fable::autoplot

Tags: r, time-series, fable, autoplot

I'm using example data from the *Forecasting: Principles and Practice* textbook chapter on VAR models [here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/VAR.html) to make forecast plots using the `fable` package.

I'd like to be able to select a single plot from those returned by `autoplot`. For example, in the code below, how can I select and display the plot for `Income` only? I'd also like to be able to access the forecast point values and upper and lower bounds for the model with `Income` as the response variable.

When I try to see the results of the `forecast()` call, I get an "ERROR while rich displaying an object" so I can't see how to subset this object. This could be because I'm running this analysis on Deepnote (like a Jupyter notebook), I'm unsure. But perhaps filtering or selecting or subsetting in some way before or after calling `forecast()` will get me the data and plot I'm looking for.

```
library(fpp3)
fit <- us_change %>%
  model(
    aicc = VAR(vars(Consumption, Income)),
    bic = VAR(vars(Consumption, Income), ic = "bic")
  )
fit %>%
  select(aicc) %>%
  forecast() %>%
  autoplot(us_change %>% filter(year(Quarter) > 2010))
```

[image: us_change autoplots]

Comment: I suspect the issues with viewing the fable is due to running it on Deepnote - I'll investigate this (https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/339).
It is also not currently possible to plot just one response variable from a multivariate model, I'll add this when we transition to using the {ggdist} package for plotting forecast distributions (https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/issues/338).

Comment: Thanks @MitchellO'Hara-Wild, I think you're right as I did try again in RStudio and I didn't get the same errors. Thanks also for confirming that I can't plot just one variable at the moment, as I had thought I wasn't using the API correctly to allow that to happen. I'll go back to manual plotting and will look forward to the extra functionality in future. `fabletools` is fab!